# Quick scroll by touching scroll indicator in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I'm trying to create the effect seen in some iOS apps where swiping the screen scrolls the ScollView/TextView normally, but sliding on the far right (where the scroll indicator is) creates a quick scrolling effect that allows the user to scroll through the position in the overall length of the view. For example, sliding on the far right from the middle of the screen to the bottom would take the TextView from the middle of its content to the very end.

Is there any pre-established way to do this, or is this an effect I would have to create from scratch?

Thanks a lot for any help, and I'm sorry if this question wasn't very clear.

Comment: Looking for the same thing...